# Did Mac-OS Ventura 13.4.1 have conflict with Workbench (list view fails; must log in 1/2 dozen times to do a query)?

Tags: workbench, upgrade

MacOS updates can interfere with functionality of other applications, ex: Aqua Data Studio. Since updating to Mac-OS 13.4.1 cannot use 'View as List' at all. Error message = UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379. Which is 95% of my usage. With 'View as Bulk CSV' the connection breaks, it requests me to login multiple times; often before I can download the results. Are there any work arounds as there are for ADS?

Comment: No, MacOS updates are not the culprit here. This is an ongoing issue with Workbench (which is not an official part of Salesforce. It's a community-based Open Source project which has been in "maintenance only" mode for a while).